# Connect to the MySQL server from another PC (from java application)

Tags: java, mysql, wamp

I realized an java application that connects to MySQL.

when i make my ip adress of my pc in the navigator of another pc  in same local network ,I access to phpMyadmin  and Wamp.

When i make 127.0.0.1  on the same pc (Wamp install) I connect to 127.0.0.1 from my java application and it works .

but the problem when I put my ip address in my java application either from my pc or from another pc in same local network , I can not manage to connect  .

this is my file of configuration in the java application:

```
db.user=root
db.password=
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.59:3306/testfournisseur
```

Is there a manipulation to do?

This is the errors appear when i connect to the database:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:   Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:666)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1069)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2031)
... 72 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2431)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:590)
... 74 more
```

Comment: I doubt your mysql is running on port 80. Check that.

Comment: Quote possibly your router has a NAT and you need to setup port forwarding.

Comment: i used the port 3306 but its don't work  but i don't understand what do you mean by Quote possibly your router has a NAT?

Comment: typo, quote possibly = quite possibly. "router NAT" is something you can google.

Comment: Since you mention that this is all on the same network, I doubt NAT is the problem. If you were trying to connect from different LAN segments or from the WAN to the LAN that would make sense, but based on what we've been told I'm skeptical.

Comment: @Isaac Bennetch thanks, i found the solution, so i create a new user in phpMyadmin and i connect now with user not with Root

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with MySQL on Windows but the most common reason I see for being unable to connect is that the `bind-address` in `my.cnf` is set to `127.0.0.1`, if you change this to `0.0.0.0` or another accessible address then it should work fine.

I also noticed you specify port 80 in your properties example, MySQL runs on 3306 by default so changing the port to that (or omitting it) may work.

Edit: Windows' built-in firewall may be blocking the connection so it's definitely worth checking out.

Comment: yeah i used the port 3306 but its don't work, but where i can find the file my.cnf?

Comment: @user2222 I'll have to take a stab in the dark given I'm unfamiliar with WAMP so I'm guessing `C:\Program Files\WAMP\mysql`. It may be called `my.ini` on Windows now that I think of it.

Comment: i found the file my.ini  in C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17 but i dont find bind-address or any specification for the adress 127.0.0.1

Comment: @user2222 I see. Confirming Windows' firewall allows external access is probably a good call.

Comment: the Windows' firewall is disabled but i have the same problem , it give me this error  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Comment: @user2222 are there any suppressed exceptions? Usually that exception wraps another.

Comment: You should go to the database admin right away and have a conversation.  Stop guessing.

Comment: @Connor Spencer Harries there is no database admin, in my pc i installed the wamp server and where i have my database and i want to connect to my database  from my java application, thanks for your suggestions

Comment: @duffymo the database host and the bind address are not the same thing. It was a safe guess. OP clearly specified that he has control of the database, that would make him the admin. Somewhat of a pointless suggestion. I'm just trying to help, though I'm only familiar with MySQL on *nix and this appears to be more different than I had imagined.

Comment: @user2222 where you see the "communications link failure" exception, is there another such as timeout, connection refused, etc?

Comment: @duffymo that's why he's on here asking for help. It is rather pointless to tell someone that is stuck to ask themselves for help.

Comment: what do you want to say by is there another such as timeout , i can modifie this option max_allowed_packet = 1M? or something else

Comment: @user2222 whenever I've seen a stack trace containing the exception message you mentioned there has always been another exception that shows the actual reason the connection was unsuccessful.

Comment: @Connor Spencer Harries i edit the question, this the all errors appears when i want to connect with the database from my java application

Comment: @Connor Spencer Harries thanks a lot , i found the solution, so i create a new user in phpMyadmin and i connect now with user not with Root